# redirected to wrong html page when using express.static(__dirname) function in node.js with express

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express

I have a login page called **login.html** and an index page called **index.html**. I want to make a authentication and that only a connected user can access the index page.

I did not implement the post method on the login HTML page. I have to manually send the login username and password by going on this url:

```
http://localhost:2222/?username=a&password=b
```

Everything worked but I could not see my css, js and some other files in the index.html. To solve this problem I added this at the beginning of my code:

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname));
```

The problem is that now if I go to the localhost:2222 it shows the index.html file instead of the login.html file. Even if I use:

```
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.redirect('/login');
});
```

**How does it come ? How can I solve this ?**

The full code is:

```
var express = require("express");
var port = process.env.PORT || 2222;
var app = express();
app.use(express.static(__dirname)); 
var session = require('express-session')
app.use(session({
    secret: 'keyboardcat',
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true
}));

function checkAuth(req, res, next) {
    if (!req.session.user_id) {
        res.sendfile('login.html');
    } else {
        next();
    }
}
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.redirect('/login');
});  
app.get("/login", function(req, res) {
    if (req.query.username === 'a' && req.query.password === 'b') {
        req.session.user_id = req.query.username;
        res.redirect('index');
    } else {
        res.sendfile('login.html');
    }
});
app.get('/index', checkAuth, function(req, res){ 
    res.sendfile('index.html');
});

app.get('/logout', function (req, res) {
    delete req.session.user_id;
    res.redirect('/login');
});
```

My file tree is as follow: index.html, login.html and server.js are in a folder called *server*. In this folder sever are also 4 folders: *JS*, *CSS*, *Images* and *Random*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using project folder for static as you posted `app.use(express.static(__dirname));`. ExpressJS using `index.html` as default index page. So you need to rename `index.html` to something else like `main.html` and use `res.sendfile('main.html');`.

**Alternate Solution:**

Create a folder say `public` and put all static content(js, css and images) into `public` folder and please **do not put html file into `public` folder** and use `app.use(express.static(__dirname) + '/public');`.

Comment: This was the actual solution. I just renamed the index.html to main.html and it worked !

Answer (score 2):

It is very important that you fix your directory structure if you're using `express.static`, because at this moment, it is possible to run `http://localhost:2222/server.js` and download the server files, which is where you currently store your secrets.

What I recommend you to do is create a `server/static` directory, and place all HTML, CSS, JS, images and other assets inside, and then change this line

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname));
```

to

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/static'));
```

Additionally, you should *never, ever* send auth data through `GET` parameters like you currently do with `http://localhost:2222/?username=a&password=b`. You need to change this route into a POST request, by editing this line:

```
app.get("/login", function(req, res) {
```

to

```
app.post("/login", function(req, res) {
```

You might need to change your `form` in the HTML from `<form method="get" ...>` to `<form method="post" ...>`

Comment: I made the changes that you suggested. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to define the root directory as a first parameter for serving static content:

```
app.use('/', express.static(__dirname));
```

Or alternatively you can use:

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/'));
```

Comment: That is not a requirement, it is a virtual path prefix option if you want to change for example `/css/main.css` to `/helloworld/css/main.css`, you'd do `app.use('/helloworld', express.static(__dirname))`.